# grep Top n Matches Across Files

Tags: grep

I'm using grep to extract lines across a set of files:

```
grep somestring *.log
```

Is it possible to limit the maximum number of matches per file? Ideally I'd just to print out n lines from each of the *.log files.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To limit 11 lines per file:

```
grep -m11 somestring *.log
```

Comment: +1 Nice. I thought I knew grep, but I guess I only nnow the legacy ones (Sun OS4, SGI Irix, HPUX 10.20 etc etc/)  In what version did `-m` appear?

Comment: @JosephQuinsey I use the `-m` option of `GNU grep` for a while (already there for Red Hat 4). Cheers

Comment: Note that grep will return 0 even if not all 11 lines were matched.  If you're using as part of a test consider: `[[ $(grep -m11 somestring *.log | wc -l) -eq 11 ]]`

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternate way of simulating it with `awk`:

```
awk 'f==10{f=0; nextfile; exit} /regex/{++f; print FILENAME":"$0}' *.log
```

#### Explanation:

- **`f==10 :`** `f` is a flag we set and check if the value of it is equal to 10. You can configure it depending on the number of lines
  you wish to match.
- **`nextfile :`** Moves processing to the next file.
- **`exit :`** Breaks out of `awk`.
- **`/regex/ :`** You're search `regex` or `pattern`.
- **`{++f;print FILENAME":"$0} :`** We increment the flag and print the filename and line.

Comment: Thanks, could this be modified to print out the last n matches?

Comment: @PaulDixon You mean print last 10 matches for each file?

Comment: Yes, maybe I should ask it as different question

Comment: Here is the separate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9011841/grep-last-n-matches-across-files

Comment: Thanks @PaulDixon .. sorry got caught up in work so could not reply sooner. I have posted an answer but looks like you already found one. :)