# grep Last n Matches Across Files

Tags: shell, grep

I'm using grep to extract lines across a set of files:

grep somestring *.log

Is it possible to limit the maximum number of matches per file to the last n matches from each file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well I think grep does not support to limit N matches from the end of file so this is what you have to do

```
ls *.log | while read fn; do grep -iH create "$fn" | tail -1; done
```

Replace `tail -1` -1 with N. (-H options is to print the file name else it wont be printed if you are grep in a single file and thats exactly we are doing above)

NOTE: Above soln will work fine with file names with spaces.

**For N matches from the start of the file**

```
grep -i -m1 create *.log
```

Replace `-m1` 1 with N.

Comment: Using `ls` like that can be a very bad idea. Here it is [why](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)?

Comment: @Jaypal 'very bad idea' well if the log files in above case are created by known sources then it does not make sense to over-engineer  the soln. And if they are not, then I can understand the added complexity.

Comment: `grep pattern file | tail -1` will do

Answer (score 1):

Kind of off the cuff here, but read this [How to do something to every file in a directory using bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310422/how-to-do-something-to-every-file-in-a-directory-using-bash) as a starting point. Here's my take, assuming just the last 20 matches from each file.

```
for i in * 
do
  if test -f "$i" 
  then
    grep somestring $i | tail -n 20
  fi
done
```

Might not be completely correct, don't have files in front of me to check with, but should be a starting point.

Answer (score 1):

```
for file in /path/to/logs/*.log 
do 
   tail <(grep -H 'pattern' "$file")
done
```

This will list last 10 matches as `tail` by default lists last 10 lines. If you wish to get a different number then the following would help -

```
for file in /path/to/logs/*.log 
do 
   tail -n number <(grep -H 'pattern' "$file")
done
```

where `number` can be your number of lines

Answer (score 0):

**Last** occurrence of *search pattern* in every log file under current directory:

```
find . -name \*log\* | xargs -I{} sh -c "grep --color=always -iH pattern {} | tail -n1"
```

**First** occurrence of *search pattern* in every log file under current directory:

```
find . -name \*log\* | xargs -I{} sh -c "grep --color=always -iH pattern {} | head -n1"
```

replace `1` in `-n1` with number of occurrences you want

---

Alternatively you can use `find`'s `-exec` option instead of `xargs`

```
find . -name \*log\* -exec sh -c "grep --color=always -iH pattern {} | tail -n1" \;
```

---

You can use `-mtime` with `find` to limit down your search of log files to, let's say 5 days

`find . -mtime -5 -name \*log\* | xargs -I{} sh -c "grep --color=always -iH pattern {} | tail -n1"`